# How to apply custom angular directive logic after kendo grid render completed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am creating a custom angular directive to disable elements like input,anchor,button etc for a page containing kendo grids...

Directive works fine on other elements but not on kendo grids...few columns of the grid is having anchor tags need to disable them...

My question here is

How to apply custom logic present in my directive after kendo grid render completed...by emiting or broadcasting some action on databound event or etc...or by watching a rootscope value and changing it...

What would be the best approach i can take...will update the question soon with some codes...posting this from mobile...

Comment: I am into same problem...let me know if you find any solution. :)